# Django url: I want to match this param, how to write the regex?

Tags: regex, django, url, django-views

url scheme sample:

```
http://domain/tests/?_=1111111&data=3333333&status=22222222
```

In view, I need data and status, any approach is welcome! All the params are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data passed as GET parameters does not need to be matched in urls file.

```
urlpatterns += patterns(
    ('^tests/$', 'app.views.test'),
)
```

You will have that data in your view as: `request.GET.get('_', None)`, ...

Your can write a form which will help you to validate and clean up the data and use it like this in your view:

```
form = some_form(data=request.GET)
if not form.is_valid():
    raise InvalidRequest()
data = form.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the url the params are accessible through the request.GET dictionary in the view method.

```
def my_view(request):
    print request.GET['data']
```

Of course if you need to validate whether the elements are in the dictionary(`'data' in request.GET`) and convert them to int prior using them like that. `int(request.GET['data'])`